# Call object event from WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I need to raise objects event in WinForm. 
Need to change control state (in UI) when object property has been changed. How can I raise objects event in UI?

EDIT: On form i have 2 drop downs binded to object properties. I need to disable second drop down when selection on first one is false.

Comment: You have to be more specific or you can give an example to better show your problem.

Comment: Look at [INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you object already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, you can do the following inside your `WinForm` class:

```
yourObject.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Name") {
            //Check the value of the property here, etc...
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }
    };
```

In that example, `Name` is the property you want to monitorize.

Answer (score 0):

You can't raise object's event. Only object can raise it's event. You can only subscribe to object's event. Why? Because event is actually a pair of methods for adding and removing handlers. It's not same as property of delegate type, which you can invoke from any place.

So, you should do something which will cause object to raise that event. There is no way to raise event directly.

---

Here is sample of `INotifyPropertyChanged` usage:

```
// your object
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _bar;

    public bool Bar
    {
        get { return _bar; }
        set { 
            if (_bar == value)
                return;

            _bar = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

And bind your control to this object:

```
yourControl.DataBindings.Add("Enabled", foo, "Bar");
```

When `Bar` property will be changed, foo object will raise event, and your control will handle that event.

Comment: Actually, I need to disable control when object property is set to false. So I should use control change event which will handle object event?

Comment: @user1997418 can you change source code of your object? If yes, then you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface by your object. And make your object raise PropertyChanged event when it's property changed. Then subscribe to that event and disable control.

Comment: Well, i'm using CSLA, which raise NotifyPropertyChanged by itself. All i need to do is to disable control in Form when objects property is set to false.

Comment: @user1997418 see my last sample with data binding to `Enabled` property